# Error: Cannot find module './output-root-relative'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, module

I am building an app with Ionic and Angular. Everything has been OK during three months until today when I restarted the terminal with control C (Something y usually do). Suddenly it gives me this error

```
[ng] Module build failed (from ./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js):
[ng] Error: Cannot find module './output-root-relative'
```

in all the pages that I have created. In my localhost I only have a cannot Get message.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done a Ionic/Angular update?
In any case, Please run the below to get the detailed output and then we can see what the error is

ionic cordova build android --prod --release

Comment: Hello, I am not using Cordova and I tried to update ionic but it's still the same